# convert string to datetime in specific format

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I have date string as:

```
Fri Oct 25 22:52:21 2013
```

I want to convert it into datetime format while sending it to database.

**I tried query as:**

```
insert into
 DeccoRaw values
 ( 'A04','005629','ARROW STEPLADDER 3TREAD    13013',
 19.89,1,35.8,'NETT',19.89,'5010845130133',
 cast('Fri Oct 25 22:52:21 2013' as DateTime),
 20,'LADDERS','D19206','A','N','13013',29,'','','','','')
```

I am using c#.net

**Its giving me error:**

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

When I convert it in c# as: `DateTime.Parse('Fri Oct 25 22:52:21 2013')`

**Error:**

> string was not recognized as valid datetime

Comment: Why not convert it using a DateTime method, instead of doing this in the query?

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg it gives me error : string was not recognized as valid datetime

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the DateTime method. Look at the link below for information on how to convert using DateTime.

[How to: Convert a String to a DateTime in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx)

Also it is easier to maintain when converting the data before you send it to the database. Unless you specificly want to convert it with SQL. Then I suggest you have a look at the link below:

[How to: Convert a String to DateTime in SQL Server](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Due to non-standard format, you might need to parse the stirng with ParseExact before inserting it into DB:

```
string dateString = "Fri Oct 25 22:52:21 2013";
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: sir, when i have 'Fri Oct  5 22:52:21 2013' as string its giving me error

Comment: @SagarS.Dhanorkar, if your date can be 1 or 2 digits, use `d` instead of `dd` format. Updated the answer with this. For further reference you can use [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) with format specifiers

Answer (score 2):

Substring to remove the first chars as you dont the day of the week name. I'm not sure that it is always 3 chars so you might want to add some kind of test to find the first instance of space.

```
declare @crap as nvarchar(2000)
set @crap = 'Fri Oct 25 22:52:21 2013'
select CONVERT(datetime , substring(@crap,4,len(@crap)))
```

You could then use that directly in an insert Something like this maybe

```
insert into DeccoRaw values
 ( 'A04','005629','ARROW STEPLADDER 3TREAD    13013',
   19.89,1,35.8,'NETT',19.89,'5010845130133',
   CONVERT(datetime , substring('Fri Oct 25 22:52:21 2013' ,4,len('Fri Oct 25 22:52:21   2013' )))       
   20,'LADDERS','D19206','A','N','13013',29,'','','','','')
```

Crazy way of doing it but you said you wanted strickly sql.

Answer (score 0):

try to check the type of your date in your data base otherwise the format used by such short date, long ... and in this format you convert the string via DateTime
[convert date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspxy/cc165448.aspxn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx)